# When applying for a job js error causing me not to upload a file

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The new jobs section if I click the shiny blue **Apply** button for jobs that allow stackoverflow to handle submitting cv's is not letting me upload a file.  The page is presenting some js errors indicating **drop is not found**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Console window:

[image]

Comment: Well that doesn't seem right. Thanks for reporting - taking a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This should be fixed now!